# Disaggregate data by date from a higher timeframe to a lower one with lag

Tags: r

I have two large sets of data, one that has value/timestamp pair a  on a very shot time frame and the other is the same pair, but on a daily timeframe. What I would like to do is apply the daily value of the prior day to the current day on the lower timeframe. For example:

set 1:

```
timestamp           value
2019-10-03 23:24:00 2
2019-10-03 23:27:00 2
2019-10-03 23:30:00 3
2019-10-03 23:33:00 4
2019-10-03 23:36:00 4
2019-10-03 23:39:00 5
2019-10-03 23:42:00 5
2019-10-03 23:45:00 5
2019-10-03 23:48:00 5
2019-10-03 23:51:00 5
2019-10-03 23:54:00 5
2019-10-03 23:57:00 8
2019-10-04 0:00:00  8
2019-10-04 0:03:00  8
2019-10-04 0:06:00  8
2019-10-04 0:09:00  5
2019-10-04 0:12:00  5
2019-10-04 0:15:00  8
2019-10-04 0:18:00  6
2019-10-04 0:21:00  6
2019-10-04 0:24:00  6
2019-10-04 0:27:00  6
2019-10-04 0:30:00  7
2019-10-04 0:33:00  7
2019-10-04 0:36:00  7
2019-10-04 0:39:00  7
2019-10-04 0:42:00  7
```

set 2:

```
date    value2
2019-10-01  20
2019-10-02  40
2019-10-03  35
2019-10-04  14
2019-10-05  99
2019-10-06  23
2019-10-07  11
2019-10-08  67
2019-10-09  44
2019-10-10  32
2019-10-11  78
```

Desired Output:

```
timestamp         value value2
2019-10-03 23:24:00 2   40
2019-10-03 23:27:00 2   40
2019-10-03 23:30:00 3   40
2019-10-03 23:33:00 4   40
2019-10-03 23:36:00 4   40
2019-10-03 23:39:00 5   40
2019-10-03 23:42:00 5   40
2019-10-03 23:45:00 5   40
2019-10-03 23:48:00 5   40
2019-10-03 23:51:00 5   40
2019-10-03 23:54:00 5   40
2019-10-03 23:57:00 8   40
2019-10-04 0:00:00  8   35
2019-10-04 0:03:00  8   35
2019-10-04 0:06:00  8   35
2019-10-04 0:09:00  5   35
2019-10-04 0:12:00  5   35
2019-10-04 0:15:00  8   35
2019-10-04 0:18:00  6   35
2019-10-04 0:21:00  6   35
2019-10-04 0:24:00  6   35
2019-10-04 0:27:00  6   35
2019-10-04 0:30:00  7   35
2019-10-04 0:33:00  7   35
2019-10-04 0:36:00  7   35
2019-10-04 0:39:00  7   35
2019-10-04 0:42:00  7   35
```

And that would go on and on through the rest of the data set. I have been focused on dplyr, and have tried to get this to work using lubridate too, but I am not sure exactly how to get everything to work. I have also tried to convert the timestamps to different factors, so they would play nice with each other, but I really haven't made progress in any direction.

Comment: Are your `value2` is "Desired Output" correct? Shouldn't they be `35`, then `14`? If this is correct, I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Also, was it a typo that the days were not zero-padded in your set 2? If this was not a typo and your dates have different formats, then my solution below won't work and you have to go through the trouble of converting to dates as Ronak shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract -1 from date in `df1` and join the data with `df2` by `date`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>%
  mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp), 
         date = as.Date(timestamp) - 1) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% mutate(date = ymd(date)), by ='date')
```

This returns

```
#             timestamp value       date value2
#1  2019-10-03 23:24:00     2 2019-10-02     40
#2  2019-10-03 23:27:00     2 2019-10-02     40
#3  2019-10-03 23:30:00     3 2019-10-02     40
#4  2019-10-03 23:33:00     4 2019-10-02     40
#5  2019-10-03 23:36:00     4 2019-10-02     40
#6  2019-10-03 23:39:00     5 2019-10-02     40
#7  2019-10-03 23:42:00     5 2019-10-02     40
#8  2019-10-03 23:45:00     5 2019-10-02     40
#9  2019-10-03 23:48:00     5 2019-10-02     40
#10 2019-10-03 23:51:00     5 2019-10-02     40
#11 2019-10-03 23:54:00     5 2019-10-02     40
#12 2019-10-03 23:57:00     8 2019-10-02     40
#13 2019-10-04 00:00:00     8 2019-10-03     35
#14 2019-10-04 00:03:00     8 2019-10-03     35
#15 2019-10-04 00:06:00     8 2019-10-03     35
#16 2019-10-04 00:09:00     5 2019-10-03     35
#17 2019-10-04 00:12:00     5 2019-10-03     35
#18 2019-10-04 00:15:00     8 2019-10-03     35
#19 2019-10-04 00:18:00     6 2019-10-03     35
#20 2019-10-04 00:21:00     6 2019-10-03     35
#21 2019-10-04 00:24:00     6 2019-10-03     35
#22 2019-10-04 00:27:00     6 2019-10-03     35
#23 2019-10-04 00:30:00     7 2019-10-03     35
#24 2019-10-04 00:33:00     7 2019-10-03     35
#25 2019-10-04 00:36:00     7 2019-10-03     35
#26 2019-10-04 00:39:00     7 2019-10-03     35
#27 2019-10-04 00:42:00     7 2019-10-03     35
```

---

In base R, you can write the same code as :

```
df1$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df1$timestamp, format = '%Y-%m-%d %T', tz = 'UTC')
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$timestamp) - 1
df2$date <- as.Date(df2$date)
merge(df1, df2, by = 'date')
```

Comment: Brilliant. I made that problem way harder than I needed to. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother converting your strings to dates, you can use regular expressions:

```r
df1$date <- sub("(.*) .*", "\\1", df1$timestamp)
result <- merge(df1, df2, by = "date")
result$date <- NULL
```

---

Demo with minimal data:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  timestamp = c("2019-10-03 23:24:00", "2019-10-03 23:27:00", "2019-10-04 0:15:00"),
  value = c(2, 2, 8)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  date = c("2019-10-01", "2019-10-03", "2019-10-04"),
  value2 = c(20, 35, 14)
)

df1$date <- sub("(.*) .*", "\\1", df1$timestamp)
result <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'date')
result$date <- NULL
```

Output:

```r
> result
            timestamp value value2
1 2019-10-03 23:24:00     2     35
2 2019-10-03 23:27:00     2     35
3  2019-10-04 0:15:00     8     14
```